# How to select records with a combination of values exist between two tables

Tags: sql

I cannot figure this one out, I want to check these two tables, where ALL LadReady are 'Shi' for a given LadSeries. This query is almost there... but 410 should not be in the results because there is clearly one record where LadReady is 'Yes' instead of 'Shi'.

Query:

```
SELECT     Shipping.LadReady, 
           Shipping.LadSeries, 
           Drawings.Job, 
           Drawings.Series, 
           Drawings.Status, 
           Drawings.DShopStatus, 
           Drawings.SeriesInv 
FROM Shipping 
LEFT JOIN Drawings ON Drawings.Job = Shipping.LadJob 
AND Drawings.Series = Shipping.LadSeries 
WHERE Drawings.Job='22925' 
AND Shipping.LadReady='Shi' 
AND Drawings.Status='Shop Issued' 
AND DShopStatus='Complete'
AND (NOT Drawings.SeriesInv='Invoiced' AND NOT SeriesInv='Part Invoiced')
```

Table: Shipping

```
LadReady | LadJob | LadSeries 
-----------------------------
Shi      | 22925  | 410
Shi      | 22925  | 410
Yes      | 22925  | 410
Shi      | 22925  | 100
Shi      | 22925  | 100
Shi      | 22925  | 200
```

Table: Drawings

```
Job   | Series |  Status      | DShopStatus | SeriesInv
-------------------------------------------------------
22925 | 410    | Shop Issued  | Complete    | Not Invoiced
22925 | 100    | Shop Issued  | Complete    | Not Invoiced
22925 | 200    | Shop Issued  | Complete    | Invoiced
```

Results:

```
 LadReady | LadSeries| Job   | Series | Status       | DShopStatus | SeriesInv
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Shi       | 410      | 22925 | 410    | Shop Issued  | Complete    | Not Invoiced
Shi       | 100      | 22925 | 100    | Shop Issued  | Complete    | Not Invoiced
```

The first result above, 410 should NOT be there because we have one record that is LadReady='Yes' instead of 'Shi'.

Comment: I should mention I am using Microsoft SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query. first restrict the `shipping` rows to be only the valid ones, then join it to `drawings`

```
with valid as (
    select Max(ladready) ladready, ladjob, ladseries
    from shipping
    where ladjob=22925
    group by ladjob, ladseries
    having Count(*)=Count(case when ladready='Shi' then 1 end)
)
select v.LadReady, v.LadSeries, d.Job, d.Series, d.DShopStatus, d.SeriesInv
from valid v
join drawings d on d.series=v.ladseries 
    and d.DShopStatus='complete' 
    and d.status='shop issued'
    and not (d.SeriesInv in ('Invoiced','Part Invoiced'))
```

Comment: I tried this but it's removing records it shouldn't. I don't understand why Max(ladready)? Also the records remaining are being duplicated.

Comment: @ohgodpleasehelpme See [this example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c38f98401477e517bbfd20cccbc8feec) working with your test data, the results are as you describe?

Comment: Sorry, bad description... when I run it on my server, there are more records than I used in the example. This is pulling more d.Jobs, not restricting to 22925. This appears to be super close. I will play around with it.

Comment: simply add another "AND d.Job='22925'" to the end of your query and it now provides the expected results!

Comment: Ah ok of course - in which case you just need to add the correlation `and d.job=v.ladjob` I missed that - test data with a couple of varied values would have caught it :)

Comment: Right. I will add this. I don't think it will make a difference as once you are within one job #, you shouldn't technically encounter another. But adding it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which dbms are you using, this is tested on `MySQL` and `SQL Server`.

Add below condition to remove all the `LadSeries` who are at least one time `Yes`

```
      Shipping.LadSeries NOT IN (
                                select distinct Shipping.LadSeries 
                                from Shipping
                                where Shipping.LadReady ='YES' );


select s.LadReady,s.LadSeries,d.Job,d.Series,d.Status,d.DShopStatus,d.SeriesInv
from Drawings d
inner join Shipping s on d.Job=s.LadJob and d.Series=s.LadSeries
where d.Job=22925
and s.LadReady='Shi'
and d.Status='Shop Issued' 
and d.DShopStatus='Complete'
and d.SeriesInv not in ('Invoiced','Part Invoiced')
and s.LadSeries NOT IN (
                         select distinct Shipping.LadSeries 
                         from Shipping
                          where Shipping.LadReady ='YES' )
group by s.LadReady,s.LadSeries,d.Job,d.Series,d.Status,d.DShopStatus,d.SeriesInv;
```

Demo `MySQL`: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/177

Demo `SQL Server`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=784990a572531ef9d4063926d8e55ec1

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention I am using Microsoft SQL; this doesn't appear to be working there.

Comment: @ohgodpleasehelpme it works on SQL Server check demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=784990a572531ef9d4063926d8e55ec1

Comment: I'm just getting no results at all on my server, I don't understand it... I will keep trying!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `cte`:

```
with cte(id, c, s) as (
   select s.ladseries, count(*), sum(s.ladready="Shi") from shipping s group by s.ladseries
)
select "Shi", d.* from drawings d join cte c on d.series = c.id and c.c = c.s where d.seriesinv = 'Not Invoiced'
```

Comment: This gives me incorrect syntax error. I don't quite understand the cte function, but I will investigate more, thank you.